# Haskell - Reverse polish notation regular expression to expression tree

Tags: regex, haskell, expression-trees, postfix-notation

Im struggling with coming up with algorithm that converts a regular expression (in context of regular languages, there are only 3 operations '.' for concat, '+' for "or" and '*' for iteration) in reverse polish notation to the regular expression tree.

For example i have a regular expression

```
aa.bb.+
```

for which i need to construct following expression tree

```
      +
    /   \
   .     .
  / \   / \
 b   b a   a
```

Would appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: I think that algorithms for parsing expressions in RPN are fairly well known. How about the one [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation#Postfix_algorithm). If you've tried to implement something you should include your attempts.

Comment: I had hard time understanding implementation of stack in Haskell, that's why I didn't go for such solution. Thanks to Carsten, now I understand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not hard to do using an stack-based algorithm (which translates into a `foldl` in Haskell):

```
data Tree
  = Symbol Char
  | Op Char Tree Tree
  deriving Show

type Stack = [Tree]

step :: Stack -> Char -> Stack
step (r:l:s) '.' = (Op '.' l r):s
step (r:l:s) '+' = (Op '+' l r):s
step s c         = (Symbol c):s

parse :: String -> Stack
parse = foldl step []
```

which would yield something like this:

```
λ> parse "aa.bb.+"
[Op '+' (Op '.' (Symbol 'a') (Symbol 'a')) (Op '.' (Symbol 'b') (Symbol 'b'))]
```

you did not write *anything* about your data-structures so I took some liberties - it should be easy to adapt to your situation once you understood `step` and the `foldl` in `parse`

---

if you want to change *left*/*right* as in your example you just have to do it in `step`:

```
step :: Stack -> Char -> Stack
step (l:r:s) '.' = (Op '.' l r):s
step (l:r:s) '+' = (Op '+' l r):s
step s c         = (Symbol c):s
```

example:

```
λ> parse "aa.bb.+"
[Op '+' (Op '.' (Symbol 'b') (Symbol 'b')) (Op '.' (Symbol 'a') (Symbol 'a'))]
```

but I would expect the first one if the order would matter (here you have `bb` before `aa` which is strange ...

---

of course it's strange that the *star* operation is binary too so I would suggest:

```
data Tree
  = Symbol Char
  | Concat Tree Tree
  | Star Tree
  deriving Show

type Stack = [Tree]

step :: Stack -> Char -> Stack
step (r:l:s) '.' = (Concat r l):s
step (t:s)   '+' = (Star t):s
step s c         = (Symbol c):s

parse :: String -> Stack
parse = foldl step []
```

which would change your syntax a bit:

```
λ> parse "aa.bb..+"
[Star (Concat (Concat (Symbol 'b') (Symbol 'b')) (Concat (Symbol 'a') (Symbol 'a')))]
```

but which seems saner IMO

---

#### convert list to Maybe

of course you might not like the `[Stack]` return so you could do this:

```
parse :: String -> Maybe Tree
parse input =
  case result of
    [t] -> Just t
    []  -> Nothing
    _   -> error "syntax error"
  where result = foldl step [] input
```

examples:

```
λ> parse "aa.bb..+"
Just (Star (Concat (Concat (Symbol 'b') (Symbol 'b')) (Concat (Symbol 'a') (Symbol 'a'))))
λ> parse ""
Nothing
λ> parse "aa.bb.+"
*** Exception: syntax error
```

Comment: Thank you kindly, Carsten. This solution really opened my eyes.