# How can a haskell function work if the function ignores its 1st arg?

Tags: haskell

My question regards the code in the Answer of the question at
[Haskell - Reverse polish notation regular expression to expression tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36277160/haskell-reverse-polish-notation-regular-expression-to-expression-tree).
I've duplicated the code here so you needn't follow the above link:

```
data Tree
  = Symbol Char
  | Op Char Tree Tree
  deriving Show

type Stack = [Tree]

step :: Stack -> Char -> Stack
step (r:l:s) '.' = (Op '.' l r):s
step (r:l:s) '+' = (Op '+' l r):s
step s c         = (Symbol c):s

parse :: String -> Stack
parse = foldl step []
```

I put the code above in a file, added main that calls parse with arg "aa.bb.+" and got result matching that at the original question.

My question: How does parse work if its 1st arg (the expression to be parsed) is ignored?  How can step work if it doesn't receive its second arg?

In my file I replaced:

```
parse = foldl step []
```

with:

```
parse s = foldl step [] s
```

Resulting program also works correctly and seems "more correct" since parse now uses its arg.

Comment: I find it interesting that you are okay with passing `step` as an argument to `foldl`, and not, say, `(\stack char -> step stack char)`. Or perhaps you found that confusing as well and just didn't mention it!

Comment: Welcome to the world of currying & HOF!

Answer (score 13):

`parse` does not ignore its argument. To a first approximation, the expressions `\x -> f x` and `f` mean the same thing whenever both typecheck; similarly, to a first approximation, the definitions `f = g` and `f x = g x` mean the same thing whenever both typecheck.

Okay, okay, maybe you don't like my bare assertion. Here's another argument you may find convincing. Consider this expression:

```
parse "aa.bb.+"
```

If we take the equality `parse = foldl step []` seriously, then this should be the same thing as

```
foldl step [] "aa.bb.+"
```

simply by substituting one side of the equation for the other. This `foldl` expression patently does not ignore the final string.

Answer (score 5):

All functions in Haskell take a single argument; ones that *appear* to take multiple arguments really return another function, not the "ultimate" return value. That is, `foldl step []` is not a single call to `foldl`; it's one call to `foldl`, and then another call to the function that `foldl step` returns. Because function application is left-associative, you can write `foldl step []` instead of `(foldl step) []`.

Answer (score 2):

This is also known as pointfree or tacit programming where a single argument function doesn't have that argument explicitly stated.

[Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tacit_programming)

Also nifty: [site that lets you convert code to pointfree style](http://pointfree.io/)